# Prove that:$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\ge8(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ Prove that:$$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\ge8(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$

Again, I think of Schur, and the inequality is reversed again. By Schur, $$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\ge 8xyz$$ and we need to prove $$xyz\ge(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$
But in fact, $$(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}\ge xyz$$
I know my problem is if $a\ge b$,$a\ge c$, it isn't mean that $b\ge c$, please help me with this question and can you give me some experience to get out of this wrong way of thinking so that there can be many new directions?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac 8 3$ instead of $8$ on the right hand side?

Comment: $$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8/9(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposition**. $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\geq \frac 83(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$

To prove the Proposition, one uses the following lemma hinted by Paresseux Nguyen.

**Lemma**. $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\geq \frac 89(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$

*Proof*. One uses the elementary symmetric polynomials: $$s_1=x+y+z,s_2=xy+yz+zx,s_3=xyz.$$ Then the statement in the Lemma is equivalent to $$9(s_1-x)(s_1-y)(s_1-z)\geq 8s_1s_2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 9(s_1^3-s_1s_1^2+s_2s_1-s_3)\geq 8s_1s_2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow s_2s_1\geq 9s_3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z)\geq 9xyz,$$ which is true if one applies AM-GM twice. $\Box$

*Proof of the Proposition*. From the Lemma, it suffices to note that $$xy+yz+zx\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2},$$ by AM-GM. $\Box$

Answer (score 1):

I think, it should be $$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq\frac{8}{3}(x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}.$$

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2,$ where $v>0$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, $u\geq v\geq w$ and we need to prove that:
$$9uv^2-w^3\geq8uw^2$$ or
$$9uv^2\geq8uw^2+w^3,$$ which is obvious because $uv^2\geq uw^2$ and $uv^2\geq w^3$.